# How do I remove the first two characters of every row in this column using SQL?

Tags: sql

How do I remove the first two characters of every row in this column?

```
  Ticket Number
  J2F4T45T      
  J2J3J3J2
  J25TGYHJ2    
  J2FFJ2J2    
  J2MG8NGJ2
```

Comment: Hint: `SUBSTRING`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL You can use `STUFF` like this to see how it works:

`SELECT STUFF('0123456789',1,2,'')`

And then with an update

`UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN = STUFF('YOUR_COLUMN',1,2,'')`

if you were using mysql there is an similar function `INSERT()`

There are a few different ways to do this, you can play with `SUBSTRING` or even regular expressions depending on your database.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.